# How do I create two boxplots with a y axis on the left, and a y axis of different scaling on the right? Preferably base R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, boxplot

After much data manipulation, I have the tibble containing all the numbers I need to create two box plots:

```
head(final)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `Maximum Daily Precipitation` `Annual Average Precipitation`
                          <dbl>                          <dbl>
1                          159.                          1426.
2                          170.                          1556.
3                          151.                          1367.
4                          196.                          1469.
5                          150.                          1412.
6                          131.                          1204.
```

When I make a boxplot of both, I have the following:

```
boxplot(final,ylab="Precipitation")
```

[boxplot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzt6j.png)

Now while the data is correct, I was hoping to present it better by setting two y axes with different scales on the left and on the right. Im looking to set the y axis on the left to go from 0 to 200, and the y axis on the right to go from 0 to 2100.

Im new to R and would like to know if this is possible using Base R? If not, using ggplot2.

Thank you.

Comment: In base R, the following has you covered: `?layout`, `?split.screen`, `par(mfcol = c(1,2))` and `?axis` (perhaps together with `?pretty`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ggplot2` this is one way to do it:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(maxd_prec = c(159, 170, 151, 196, 150, 131),
                     aavg_prec = c(1426, 1556, 1367, 1469, 1412, 1204)),
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = maxd_prec:aavg_prec, names_to = "prec_type", values_to = "prec") %>% 
  mutate(labels = ifelse(prec_type == "aavg_prec", "Annual Average Precipitation", "Maximum Daily Precipitation")) %>% 
  select(-prec_type) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = labels, y = prec)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~labels, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Precipitation")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I just renamed the variables in the tibble to what you set and it worked. I changed a the x part of aes() of ggplot() to null so the x-axis labels isn't doubled, and it looks good: `ggplot(aes(x = NULL, y = prec))`

I was asked to write the boxplots into one plot thought where one axis is on the left side, and the other on the right side, so I'm still wondering if that is possible.

I wanted to upvote yout reply but I still can't do it yet as I need 15 reputation. Sorry :(